# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android

Tengo la versiones de Android Studio (Chipmunk | 2021.2.1).

Pues bien cuando intento crear un nuevo proyecto de Navigation Drawer Activity me sale  al principio una inconsistencia de dependencias algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento añadir las librerias pero no me funciona:

El gradle es :

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
   compileSdk 33

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.valhondo.delgado.myapplication"
       minSdk 26
       targetSdk 33
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
} } dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.6'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.6'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1' }
```

y

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Ademas salen errores en en fichero contest_main.xml

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

y en el MainActivity.java con estas importacion como si no las encontrase:

```
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
```

Tambien me sale errores si creo otro proyecto que no sea uno vacio.

Gracias

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el valor de `compileSdk`, en vez de `33`, ponlo en `34`, algo así: **`compileSdk 34`**.

Comment: Sigue igual. Ademas lo he probado en la ultima version y es peor, no salen los errores pero al complidarlo  salen muchos errores, en las librerias

Comment: ¿Qué errores salen? No tienes que asustarte por ello, simplemente actualiza tus librerías. Si observas, en el archivo  gradle te van a salir con un sombreado todas las librerías que están obsoletas, conviene que las actualices todas, que hagas un nuevo Sync y que luego compiles el código. Cuando hagas eso, la mayoría de esos errores van a desaparecer.

Comment: Lo que he realizado en esta version es copiar el gradle(proyect) y gradle (module) de otro que funcionaba  (versiones libreria mas antiguas) y ha funcionado, ahora iremos modificando el proyecto y veremos. En la otra version de Android Studio (la mas moderna) ya veremos. Muchas gracias.